# Safari z-index Bug

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have two containers, and the first one has to cover a part of the second one. I did this with z-indexes, and it works just fine on desktop and on the device toolbar. But when I access the website from a mobile platform, the containers just mix themselves. I've tried webkit, translate3d and still no result. Perhaps I'm missing something.

**HTML**

```
<div class="photoContainer">
<div class="photo"> </div>
</div>

<div class="aboutMe">
    <div class="textContainer">
<br><br>
        <h2 style="text-align: center; font-weight: 700;">About Me</h2>

</div>
    </div>

<div class="projectsContainer">
    <div style="margin-top: 125px;width: 100%;text-align: center;" 
class="titleCont">
        <h2 style="font-weight: 700;">Projects</h2>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.aboutMe {
overflow: visible;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px 3px rgba(195, 192, 192, 0.92);
border-radius: 8px;
margin-top: 65px;
height: 40em;
border: 2px solid #737373;
width: 60%;
position: absolute;
left: 20%;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
}

.textContainer {
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
height: 100%;
}

.content-wrapper {
position: relative;
height: 100vh;
margin-top: 100px;
}

.photo {
text-align: center;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-image: url(//url here);
border-radius: 100%;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px 3px rgba(195, 192, 192, 0.92);
background-size: contain;
}

.photoContainer {
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999;
justify-content: center;
display: flex;
width: 100%;
}

.projectsContainer {
z-index: -10 !important;
position: relative;
top: 40em;    
width: 100%;
height: 550px;
border: 2px solid #737373;
box-shadow: 4px 3px 7px 5px rgba(195, 192, 192, 0.92);
}
```

The aboutMe container should be on top of the projectsContainer one. Why isn't it working on ios as long as it works on desktop ?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you use rgba just for color, but you forgot on alpha channel.

Set background-color on **rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)** or **#fff** or just **white**.

Comment: I have to do this for the container which has to be behind the aboutMe ?

Comment: Edit this property in class .aboutMe. Alpha channel is required in rgba.